# AWS cognito username exists exception

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using Amazon Cognito to sign-up for an application. While doing this, I'm getting "UsernameExistsException: user name already exists". I have given all forms of username, still getting this error. How to check whether the username is already registered or not? Also, please tell how to rectify this exception

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if a user already exists in Cognito by logging into the AWS Console, or by checking the [user pool users](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/users/).

If the user does not already exist, check to ensure that you are not attempting to register a user with an aliased attribute. For example, if you have set an alias for `phone_number`, all registered phone numbers must also be unique.

If you are still having trouble with this problem, can you please post any supporting code to help me answer it better?